# Create 'n' circles along a mouse created vector line paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I would like to create 'n' number of circles along a mouse created vector line when the mouse is clicked and dragged.

This would result in a row of circles which would be a certain distance apart, depending on the number of circles in the line. The first and last circles would be at the point where the mouse was first clicked and then released.

Example: If the line is 1000px long, and 3 circles are required there would be a circle at 0px 500px and 1000px. If the line is 1000px long and 5 circles are required, there would be a point at 0px, 250px, 500px, 750px and 1000px.

I had an attempt at paper.js with the following results, but this is not quite what I need. In this example, the circles follow a free path and are spaced by a set number of pixels.

[Click here to see](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/dZA9b8JADIb/yukWQELXim6pOsFaCYmx6XD4DDlibOQ40ArlvzcfpVsHD7af16/tu+d4Rl/4XY0GlV96kDTkF5UTggVoVZFtZ9+E4ZCJ1kKi7s3N9hShnr2WWvIQJkI98IVpkxuLDNhDL89//UPLYFnYCb9L2+BG43GO1372wt1HyK5RHWQFGqSMN7eNVoX1WJn/MqVBL0Et3KgN55wS4VYy2/JBaEy5bR5EQrIYCPlolXtyq4nqFtNmNhn+e1rXv2SvGOvLYNH44uOz+wE=)

As an extra, it would be nice to see the path of the mouse line before the mouse is released.

Comment: [`getPointAt(offset)`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getpointat-offset) is your friend

Comment: Thanks. That looks much simpler that my solution :) http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/VVJNb8IwDP0rUS+kKpSh3Sg7MWmnaUjsNqYpNB5ELTZKUnpA/PfF6QeslzrvOc/Pdq4JqhMky2RbgS+PyTQpSfO5Ngg/nqgWLwKhFZ8hlGmxw5HICd+pcfBq1SEk/TZYekMoJFwAfSquO7woKw6WmnMv8sZxVOk455X1DpQP/KLoMEA9IE89ZKl14Twws/u94kGHM7hyrqnFDRn0d8WROz/gNWDAu7szzhrVgA0zPReSi6c9YwI8mCoba4PihtwgEttqj6YGIY1YRdvZIg5ChG+H8zn/2bfrKx3VGfrZbDnO18aWNUgGYgvyXiadimc2Ei/lzluqYE012SAw2deqrCYjq5VXOW928MZFMxP4uI5cab0ORrWM6az6r52HwyyOIySYLCu6Nm6DioUTXeAD+QXErd7C+9lbUFUcs0uWX9+3Pw==

Comment: You are still not using `getPointAtOffset` though

Answer (score 0):

As @NicholasKyriakides wrote in his comment, this can be best implemented using a `Path` with `getPointAt(offset)`.

I have implemented this in your code example and made it more generic, so you can use any path, not only a straight line.
 I have also replaced your circle items with instances of `SymbolItem`, which is more efficient, because they share a lot of data.

[Here is the Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)